# Could not find "store " in either the context or props of "Connect(Home)"

Tags: react-native, react-redux

How to fix this error ?
  Could not find "store " in either the context or props of "Connect(Home)". Either wrap the root component in a  or explicitly   pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Home)".

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";
import { Router } from "react-native-router-flux";
import scenes from "../routes/scenes";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

export default class AppContainer extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Provider store={this.props.store}>
                <Router scenes={scenes} />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

**From the commments:**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import makeRootReducer from "./reducers";
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";

const log = createLogger({ diff: true, collapsed: true });

const store = createStore( makeRootReducer(), initialState, compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers ));
return store;
};
```

Comment: the store param in provider should be a `createStore`. Can you show the code for you create store.?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how this should be connected.

> Provider Class

```
// Third party.
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
// App modules
import setupStore from './utils/setupStore'; //This is the trick
// Assets Actions

const store = setupStore(); //==> Here calling the function inside setupStore file

// App component.
import App from './App';

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

> `./utils/setupStore` File.

```
// Node Core Third party
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
// App Modules
import rootReducer from '../store'; //Your combine reducer file

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk);

export default function configureStore() {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, middleware); //This is the createStore I was talking to you about.

    if (module.hot) {
        module.hot.accept(() => {
            const nextRootReducer = require('../store/index').default;
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
        })
    }

    return store;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `if (module.hot)`?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using `react-router` you need to follow this order:

*index.jsx* --

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router'


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <Route path="foo" component={Foo}/>
                <Route path="bar" component={App}/>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </div>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('react-app')
)
```

*package.json* --

```
"react": "^0.14.7",
"react-dom": "^0.14.7",
"react-redux": "^4.3.0",
"react-router": "^2.0.0",
"redux": "^3.2.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.0",
"webpack": "^1.9.8",
"webpack-bundle-tracker": "0.0.5",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.5"
```